# Is it possible to have exactly identical output of random effects and fixed effect models in a network meta-analysis?

Tags: random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, network-meta-analysis

I conducted a network meta-analysis in frequentist framework using the R package *netmeta* (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/netmeta/netmeta.pdf), statistical details of this package are available here (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26053424). This package generates both fixed effect and random effects results by default. Surprisingly, for my analysis, both outputs are exactly identical. How can I explain this? The number of studies in my analysis is 10. Initially, I included 12 studies in the analysis, which resulted in a high statistical heterogeneity *(I^2 >95%)*. I removed two of the studies with high heterogeneity reducing the number to 10 and a very low heterogeneity *(tau =0; I^2=0)*. Could this very low heterogeneity be the reason for exactly identical outputs? Is this approach of excluding studies to manage heterogeneity valid? As I understand, an exhaustive NMA should include all available evidence.

Studies are clinically homogenous and all are randomised trials. Most of the treatments are being compared against Placebo.

Comment: Low heterogeneity?

Comment: ndeed, heterogeneity is very low _(tau^2 = 0; I^2 = 0%)_. Actually, I removed two of the studies from this analysis that were resulting in very high heterogeneity _(I^2 >95%)_. I did pairwise meta-analyses to identify those studies and removed them from the main NMA, kept them for a sensitivity analysis, which I haven't done yet. Could you please suggest if this approach is reasonable? Could you please also elaborate more on consequences of having low heterogeneity?

Comment: If heterogeneity is very low and the number of studies limited I think it is perfectly OK. Indeed, report both results and highlight this finding. It could also depend on the fact that your evidence network is mostly star-shaped (amounting mostly to an adjusted indirect comparison...).

Comment: Without a summary of results and a brief picture of your study, it is difficult to answer your concerns.

Comment: @Joe_74 thank you for response! The number of studies is 10 with a total of 32 treatment arms. I understand getting exactly same results is not an unusual finding. Could you please also comment on my approach of excluding studies from analysis to manage heterogeneity, is this approach reasonable? Could you please also elaborate more on the "star shaped network" you mentioned?

Comment: I don't recommend to exclude studies based on their findings, but only given their design features (eg randomized trials included, non-randomized trials excluded). A star-shaped network is a network where most treatments have been compared to a single agent (eg placebo).

Comment: exactly identical output of random effects and fixed effect models  ,  which output are you talking of ? what are your effectsizes ?

Comment: I^2 = 0. How did u measure ? The formula ?

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar Method to calculate _I^2_ is published in literature and used commonly in evidence synthesis (check Higgins and Thompson [2002]). The _netmeta_ package I mentioned in my question uses the same method to quantify statistical heterogeneity. Effect size was mean diff.; however, I don't think the class of effect size can explain my question.

Comment: We develop measures of the impact of heterogeneity on a meta-analysis, from mathematical criteria, that are independent of the number of studies and the treatment effect metric. We derive and propose three suitable statistics: H is the square root of the chi2 heterogeneity statistic divided by its degrees of freedom; R is the ratio of the standard error of the underlying mean from a random effects meta-analysis to the standard error of a fixed effect meta-analytic estimate, and I2 is a transformation of (H).  This suggests that it is not a standard tool for testing the heterogeneity.

Comment: I do not know how tau square is estimated to be zero. Its formula suggests that it should not be zero. Genrally, we shoud expect certain differences in the effect-sizes.  Default setting could be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is pretty dubious to exclude studies, because their results mismatch your model. If the studies fit all your inclusion criteria, I suspect many people will feel uncomfortable about removing them to reduce betwen study heterogeneity in outcomes.

Secondly, if the between study variability is estimated to be zero (on the boundary of the parameter space) in a random effects model, there are multiple ways of dealing with that. One common option in maximum likelihood approaches is to treat the parameter as if it were known to be exactly zero, which is what the software you use seems to do.

With Bayesian approaches (either maximum-a-posteriori with boundary avoiding priors or with proper priors and looking at other posterior summaries) this is - in my personal opinion - handled in a more natural manner, but then you of course have to set priors and we know that in a meta-analysis with few studies the prior for the between-study heterogeneity can be quite influential.